# How to Include Tasks as Backlog Items?

Tags: task, azure-devops, project-management, kanban

Using Visual Studio Team Services (Online version), I would like to have a simple display for my "Backlog" and "Board" :

1. Features
2. Tasks
3. Bugs

That's pretty much it. I don't want to do anything with, iterations, sprints, user stories, etc.

This is just a one man project and I'm just wanting to see all thing on the backlog/board so I can better manage the project.

**EDIT:**

Biggest issue I had with this...

My project was setup to use the "Agile" process. I decided to try **Scrum** process instead and found this to be the deciding factor.

Once a project is set as Agile/Scrum, it cannot be cahnged... So, I Made a copy of "Scrum" process, named it "Scrum_custom", created a new project using this method, then just git pushed my existing project code to the new one.

I marked Daniel Mann's answer as correct seeing as it's what I ended up doing after changing to Scrum and it seems to be working just as I'd hoped!

Just in case anyone else reads this and is looking to do something similar, I would recommend this route...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your team configuration, you can change the backlog levels you use. In your case, you want to turn off PBI/User Story.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/select-backlog-navigation-levels

Alternately, you could just use PBI/user story instead of Feature. They're the same basic thing except with different names; it's purely a hierarchy thing:

Epic -1 to many-> Features -1 to many-> PBIs -1 to many-> Tasks

Bug behavior is configurable; they can either be treated as requirements (at the same level as a PBI) or as tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you link Task and Bug to Feature as child, you can manage them in Feature Backlog, but not Kanban board.

To link them as child, you can open a work item > Links> Add link>New Item>Select Child link type.